# How to programmatically click the Edit button in ASP.Net GridView?

Tags: gridview

I have a Gridview control on a ASPX page. The gridview has Edit and Delete links on each row.
If I click on the Edit link, the gridview enters edit mode and the links Update and Cancel will be visible.
What I need is to do the same action from code. That is from code, I have to make the browser feel that the Edit link has been clicked, and the grid enters Edit mode. But there is no handler for the Edit link in the page code.
Someone please suggest...

Comment: Client-side or server-side code?

Comment: Server side code please. The link is ASP:LinkButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at it the wrong way. You don't need to simulate a click.  What's really going on is that the gridview has an editindex property that places whatever row at that index into editmode. Which is what you want to happen.

All you have to do is figure out which row and set the editindex property of the gridview for that row.  Then rebind the gridview.

When the page loads it will have that row in the state you want it to be in.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Javalsu. I Got it. I set the row position counter to the EditIndex property and rebound the grid. It is working. Thanx

Comment: No problem.  If you had said client-side we would have been in trouble :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some events that are available in gridview.
for example, here is a sample code that saves the data from grid view into database using entity framework.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    String StudentId = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
    String Firstname = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
    String Lastname = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
    String Email = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(StudentId);
    Response.Write(StudentId);
    try
    {
        studentEntities context = new studentEntities();
        tbl_Students dbstudent = context.tbl_Students.First(i => i.Studentid == id);
        dbstudent.Firstname = Firstname;
        dbstudent.Lastname = Lastname;
        dbstudent.Email = Email;
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e1.InnerException);
    }
```